# FFMPEG Specify Local Address for SDP

Tags: ffmpeg, multicast

I have a network of AES67 devices that use multicast to communicate in a broadcast environment. I'm running FFMPEG on a machine with two NICs, one dedicated to the AES67 network and one facing the local LAN. I have an SDP file that defines how to receive from an AES67 source and is known working. However, FFMPEG doesn't know what interface to send the igmp "join" request to start getting multicast packets, so no data ends up reaching the machine.

When using an RTP input in FFMPEG, you can manually specify the local address of the interface so FFMPEG knows where to send the multicast group join request like so `rtp://239.192.0.104:5004?localaddr=192.168.2.105`. If I use that as an input, FFMPEG is able to start receiving multicast packets from the AES67 source. However, it'll fail out with the "Unable to receive RTP payload type xxx without an SDP file describing it" error because it doesn't know about the protocol type being used.

I have an SDP file that'll describe that protocol type, but once I use that as an input to FFMPEG instead of the rtp protocol, I'm unable to provide that "localaddr" parameter that tells it what NIC to use to join the multicast group. **What I need is a similar way to specify the local address of the NIC when using an SDP file.**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out that there is an **undocumented** command-line option `localaddr` that is applicable to both RTSP and SDP protocols. It will achieve the same effect as the "localaddr" parameter in the RTP URI. This really should be added to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#toc-rtsp), I ended up having to look in the source to discover it.

This will work, for example:

```
ffmpeg.exe -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -localaddr 192.168.2.105 -i '.\KPFX AIR@Node-01' test.wav
```

...while this will not, as it does not know the local address of the NIC used to request joining the multicast group:

```
ffmpeg.exe -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -i '.\KPFX AIR@Node-01' test.wav
```